# Changing a Dockerfile from CUDA9 to CUDA10

Tags: python, docker, pytorch, conda

I need to change the Dockerfile below, coming from [pytorch_geometric](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_geometric/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile) (a popular PyTorch package), from CUDA9.0 to CUDA10.0.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils ca-certificates apt-transport-https gnupg-curl && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    NVIDIA_GPGKEY_SUM=d1be581509378368edeec8c1eb2958702feedf3bc3d17011adbf24efacce4ab5 && \
    NVIDIA_GPGKEY_FPR=ae09fe4bbd223a84b2ccfce3f60f4b3d7fa2af80 && \
    apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub && \
    apt-key adv --export --no-emit-version -a $NVIDIA_GPGKEY_FPR | tail -n +5 > cudasign.pub && \
    echo "$NVIDIA_GPGKEY_SUM  cudasign.pub" | sha256sum -c --strict - && rm cudasign.pub && \
    echo "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64 /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list && \
    echo "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64 /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-ml.list

ENV CUDA_VERSION 9.0.176
ENV NCCL_VERSION 2.4.2
ENV CUDA_PKG_VERSION 9-0=$CUDA_VERSION-1
ENV CUDNN_VERSION 7.4.2.24

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        cuda-cudart-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION && \
    ln -s cuda-9.0 /usr/local/cuda && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated --no-install-recommends \
        cuda-libraries-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
        libnccl2=$NCCL_VERSION-1+cuda9.0 && \
    apt-mark hold libnccl2 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated --no-install-recommends \
        cuda-libraries-dev-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
        cuda-nvml-dev-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
        cuda-minimal-build-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
        cuda-command-line-tools-$CUDA_PKG_VERSION \
        cuda-core-9-0=9.0.176.3-1 \
        cuda-cublas-dev-9-0=9.0.176.4-1 \
        libnccl-dev=$NCCL_VERSION-1+cuda9.0 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs

# NVIDIA docker 1.0.
LABEL com.nvidia.volumes.needed="nvidia_driver"
LABEL com.nvidia.cuda.version="${CUDA_VERSION}"

RUN echo "/usr/local/nvidia/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia.conf && \
    echo "/usr/local/nvidia/lib64" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia.conf

ENV PATH /usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:${PATH}
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64

# NVIDIA container runtime.
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES all
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,utility
ENV NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA "cuda>=9.0"

# PyTorch (Geometric) installation
RUN rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list && \
    rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-ml.list 

RUN apt-get update &&  apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    ca-certificates \
    vim \
    sudo \
    git \
    bzip2 \
    libx11-6 \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create a working directory.
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Create a non-root user and switch to it.
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --shell /bin/bash user \
 && chown -R user:user /app
RUN echo "user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/90-user
USER user

# All users can use /home/user as their home directory.
ENV HOME=/home/user
RUN chmod 777 /home/user

# Install Miniconda.
RUN curl -so ~/miniconda.sh https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.12-Linux-x86_64.sh \
 && chmod +x ~/miniconda.sh \
 && ~/miniconda.sh -b -p ~/miniconda \
 && rm ~/miniconda.sh
ENV PATH=/home/user/miniconda/bin:$PATH
ENV CONDA_AUTO_UPDATE_CONDA=false

# Create a Python 3.6 environment.
RUN /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda install conda-build \
 && /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda create -y --name py36 python=3.6.5 \
 && /home/user/miniconda/bin/conda clean -ya
ENV CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=py36
ENV CONDA_PREFIX=/home/user/miniconda/envs/$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
ENV PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/bin:$PATH

# CUDA 9.0-specific steps.
RUN conda install -y -c pytorch \
    cuda90=1.0 \
    magma-cuda90=2.4.0 \
    "pytorch=1.1.0=py3.6_cuda9.0.176_cudnn7.5.1_0" \
    torchvision=0.2.1 \
 && conda clean -ya

# Install HDF5 Python bindings.
RUN conda install -y h5py=2.8.0 \
 && conda clean -ya
RUN pip install h5py-cache==1.0

# Install TorchNet, a high-level framework for PyTorch.
RUN pip install torchnet==0.0.4

# Install Requests, a Python library for making HTTP requests.
RUN conda install -y requests=2.19.1 \
 && conda clean -ya

# Install Graphviz.
RUN conda install -y graphviz=2.38.0 \
 && conda clean -ya
RUN pip install graphviz==0.8.4

# Install OpenCV3 Python bindings.
RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libgtk2.0-0 \
    libcanberra-gtk-module \
 && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN conda install -y -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0 \
 && conda clean -ya

# Install PyTorch Geometric.
RUN CPATH=/usr/local/cuda/include:$CPATH \
 && LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH \
 && DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

RUN pip install --verbose --no-cache-dir torch-scatter \
 && pip install --verbose --no-cache-dir torch-sparse \
 && pip install --verbose --no-cache-dir torch-cluster \
 && pip install --verbose --no-cache-dir torch-spline-conv \
 && pip install torch-geometric

# Set the default command to python3.
CMD ["python3"]
```

I've tried starting it with `FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.1.0-cuda10.0-cudnn7.5-runtime` and commenting everything up to `# PyTorch (Geometric) installation` and the section on `# CUDA 9.0-specific steps.` for

```
RUN conda install -c pytorch pytorch
RUN conda install -c fragcolor cuda10.0 && conda clean -ya
```

and commenting out

```
# Install Graphviz.
RUN conda install -y graphviz=2.38.0 \
 && conda clean -ya
RUN pip install graphviz==0.8.4
```

which didn't seem to work even with CUDA9.0

This makes the docker work and load, pytorch to be able to be imported and cuda to work as well. However, when I try to `import torch_geometric` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch_scatter.scatter_cuda'`

Since the package is well-maintained (4.5k stars, mentioned in the pytorch website), it seems to me it's likely my fault and something general about how to adapt from CUDA9.0 to CUDA10.0.

I'd appreciate any advice on what I could be doing wrong or a way of changing it without removing so many lines from the original Dockerfile, which is probably what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever try with `nvidia/cuda` Docker base image?

try

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.0-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        apt-utils \
        python3.6 \
        python-dev \
        python-pip \
        python-setuptools \
        && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt-get update

RUN pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3 && \
    pip --no-cache-dir install --upgrade torch==1.1.0 && \
    pip --no-cache-dir install --upgrade torchvision==0.3.0
```

The versions of the packages I wrote are stable to use with Dockerfile.
I checked it and it worked well without any collision.